# Possible to change Path in another file than java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm really new to Spring and got some questions.

One is.. in my Java class i've got a declaration of an absolute Directory path, where some Images are saved. Now if I want to send my Project to a co-worker or a friend, he needs to change the *ImagePath* in my Java Code. So I want to use a generalized technique for it, that there is a File where you can just edit the Path and the Project just works like it should.

I have heard of the method where you set up an *application.yml* and a *Configuration Class*, but I actually don't know, what to write in these Files.

Comment: What about relative paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for your problem:

1. One is to use a relative path like `src/main/resources` and put the images there.
2. Another option is to set the file path in `application.properties` file like:

   my.images.directory.path=path

And now you can use this property in your classes using @Value:
For Example:

```
@Value( "${my.images.directory.path}" )
private String imagePath;
```

Same thing you can also set in a `application.yml` file.

Also, there are other ways to set the property in the properties file and use it, which you can refer over [here](http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank You, this helped me a lot!!
First I got an error but I fixed it with putting the String to final

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a number of options when it comes to externalising configuration. In your case, the best option would be to add a property to the `application.yml` file. Ensure that you add this file to the classpath of your application. Alternatively you can specify the location of this file using `spring.config.location` command line argument.

Here is a simple application.yml file,

```
images:
    path:/usr/images
```

You can then create a configuration bean in your application to inject this property.

```
@Component
public class MyConfig {

    @Value("${images.path}")
    public String name;
}
```

Now replace hardcoded path in your application with `MyConfig.name`.

For a full list of options for externalising configuration, check out this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PropertySource` as well. Add a file in `/src/main/resources`, let's say `config.properties` containing properties.

> config.properties file

```
images.dir=/path/to/images/dir
```

In java class, say `@Controller` add `@PropertySource` as shown in test code and you will be able to access the property.

You will only be required to update the file

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Value("${images.dir}")
    private String defaultDb;

    ... 

}
```